# Viewport tag for full zoom-out on load

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, meta-tags, viewport

I have the following viewport

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=1">
```

On android, the page loads as if it were in a desktop - the whole page is viewable and zoom-out to fit the screen

on ios - the page loads without zoom-out, and what is viewable is the upper left corner of the page.

I've tried using `width=device-width` and `width=1350` but nothing seems to work

What do I need to do to make the page load so it would fit the screen fully no matter the screen size?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

I think it's most recommended meta tag.

Comment: it is the most recommended, but that particular page has a min-width which i'd like to keep on mobiles

Comment: What is your layout system? is it fluid or grid or responsive?

Comment: I think you should use (Media queries)